# Is adding a colored icon to a transparent toolbar possible?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-toolbar

Is it possible to add a circular icon like this to a transparent Toolbar (styled like an action bar), and maintain its coloring?

EDIT: this icon will be right aligned on the toolbar, similar to where you would see the three dot menu icon in most apps.

[image: Circular icon]

Comment: yes, it is posslble.

Comment: @Martin awesome, thanks. If you add this as an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to inflate a menu for the toolbar, set the background to transparent, inflate the menu with the icon.

Activity with the Toolbar

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // getSupportActionBar().hide();
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Hello World");
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                if (id == R.id.icon) {
                    // Your action here
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:title="Icon Title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually not going to have a home icon in this toolbar, just a single right aligned action icon styled similarly to the icon I linked in my question. Is that possible?

Comment: I will update my answer.  I thought it was an actionbar my mistake. Do you want this icon to be clickable?

Comment: Yes it will be actionable! It's going to be a search icon actually. Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if this is what you are looking for?

Comment: @user891242 is he example above what you are trying to accomplish?